# Collect multiple keypress events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hello this code down `append text` to `textBox` after key is pressed. It writes one line for each key press. May i ask if there is any good solution to collect for example 5 key press and write them in one line?

```
          private void User_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.AppendText(string.Format("You Wrote: - {0}\n", e.KeyChar));
        textBox.ScrollToCaret();
    }
```

For example MOUSE wouldn't be written like:

`You Wrote: M;
You Wrote: O;
You Wrote: U;
You Wrote: S;
You Wrote: E`

But the output will be:

`You wrote: MOUSE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
string testCaptured = string.Empty;
int keyPressed = 0;

private void User_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (keyPressed < 5)
    {
        testCaptured += e.keyChar;
        keyPressed++;
    }
    else
    {
        textBox.Text = string.Format("You Wrote: - {0}\n", testCaptured);
        textBox.ScrollToCaret();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `textBox.AppendText`.  Appending adds to an existing string and combines them.

You want to write something like `textBox.Text = String.Format(...)`

You should create a private variable in your object to keep track of all the characters and append to that.  The class which owns your `User_KeyPress` method should have a variable like the following:

`private string _keysPressed = String.Empty;`

Now in your method you can append and output like so:

```
private void User_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    _keysPressed += e.KeyChar;
    textBox.Text = String.Format("You Wrote: - {0}\n", _keysPressed);
    textBox.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but wouldn't not-using `.AppendText` mean that what was previously written will be over-wrote with the new `keypress` event?

Answer (score 1):

You could buffer the key presses until you reach a threshold and then output the entire buffer's contents.

e.g.

```
Queue<char> _buffer = new Queue<char>();

private void User_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  _buffer.Enqueue(e.KeyChar);

  if(_buffer.Count > 5)
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("You Wrote: ");
    while(_buffer.Count > 0)
      sb.AppendFormat(" {0}", _buffer.Dequeue());

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
  }
}
```